# Help using the jQuery BBQ plug-in with forms

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to figure out how to use the jQuery BBQ plug-in.

I have been able to add it to my site by copying the code from the site but I'm seeing that if I have a form in one of my tabs, I can't post any of the results successfully.

Has anyone used this plug-in and gotten used to its functionality? I need help figuring out where to input my php code for form handling and have the results returned the page loaded in the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how I have done it recently. This seems to work really well. I messed around with a bunch of these different jquery deeplinking tools until finally I realized BBQ is simply the best.

```
  $("form").live('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.dir(event);
    var url = $.bbq.getState( "url" );

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            error=true;
            //alert("communication error");
            handler(XMLHttpRequest.responseText,error);
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: $("form:not(#UserLoginForm)").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('.content').html(data.html);
            var href = data.address;
            var url = $.bbq.getState( "url" );
            $.bbq.pushState({ url : href });
            //console.dir(data);
            console.log("loaded new page");
            //alert('Load was performed.');
            bindFunc();     
        }
    });
```